# Python install highest version of a package

Tags: python, pip, versioning, setup.py

In my main package ***setup.py*** file 'install_requires' field i have specified some dependecies that are in git repositories. I have this line:

```
my_other_package==1.0.*
```

Lets say currently i have installed ***my_other_package 1.0.2***

Now i have made some changes and pushed a new tag ***my_other_package 1.0.3***

How can i ensure that next time i install my main package, the ***my_other_package*** would automatically be upgraded to the highest PATCH version possible leaving MAJOR and MINOR versions untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

✓ If you do not specify the version number while installing package, **pip** automatically identifies the latest release and installs it for you.

> Let suppose, your package manager is **pip** for this example. Please comment if you want more explanation about this.

✓ Let suppose the latest version of **Django** is **2.0** and it also has older versions as **1.10**, **1.8** etc.

✓ So if you prefer **pip install Django==1.8** it will only install Django 1.8 while **pip install Django** will install the latest version i.e. **2.0**.

Finally,

> You have to prefer **pip install my_other_package** to install your updated package.

Answer (score 1):

just leave it like that:

```
# requirements.txt   
my_other_package
```

If you don't specify the version, pip will pick the last one automatically.